# Running Python Scripts using task scheduler and bat files not working

Tags: python, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

This seems to be a recurrent question in many forums but after applying most of the solutions found, it's still not working.

The end of my python scripts creates two CSV files using the following code:

```
file1.to_csv(csvfilename, sep=",", encoding='utf-8', index=False)
file2.to_csv(csvfilename2, sep=",", encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

I created a bat file within the same folder of my python script with the following code in:

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\Python35\python.exe" "Pythonscript1.py"
```

And in the task scheduler i created a task. I added an action and modified the Program/script with the path of my bat file:

```
"C:\Users\name\PycharmProjects\Templates\executePy.bat"
```

After run the task, no csv files have been created.

Comment: Have you tried adding the absolute path of your python script in your bat file?

Comment: how should i do this, add it before the file name within the quotation marks?

Comment: That should work fine.

Comment: As @busybear said, use the absolute path to your script. Also you may want to try setting the "Start in" parameter for the action in task scheduler.

Comment: why is the task status showing as running after 30 mns? it appears it works

Comment: it works now, can you add as an answer so I can approve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task scheduler is not working in the directory your Python script is in. It's best to point to the script using its absolute path to avoid ambiguity.